# How to fix maker at center with dragable map and pick the new location on drag end?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

**I am working on google maps and I am trying to drag my map(camera position) without changing marker. Marker should be at center and to pick the location when I stop dragging**

This is my complete code of map functionality:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            Color(0xFFF2F2F4),
            Color(0xFFF2F2F4),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          body: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: _initialCameraPosition, zoom: 13),
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    markers: _createMarker(),
                    onCameraMove: ((_position) => _updatePosition(_position)),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.w, vertical: 12.h),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.w),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back,
                            color: Constants.colorTheme,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              DraggableScrollableSheet(
                initialChildSize: 0.4,
                minChildSize: 0.4,
                maxChildSize: 0.65,
                builder: (context, controller) => Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.r)),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: controller,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 22.w, right: 22.w, bottom: 22.w, top: 10.h),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 5,
                              width: 50,
                              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  final sessionToken = const Uuid().v4();
                                  var result = await showSearch(
                                    context: context,
                                    delegate: AddressSearch(sessionToken),
                                  );
                                  if (result != null) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      String address = '';
                                      address = result.description;
                                      strSearchedAddress = address;
                                      log(result.lat.toString());
                                      log(result.long.toString());
                                      strLongitude = result.long.toString();
                                      strLatitude = result.lat.toString();
                                      _mapsController.animateCamera(
                                        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                                          CameraPosition(
                                              target: LatLng(
                                                  double.parse(strLatitude),
                                                  double.parse(strLongitude)),
                                              zoom: 18),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                      _initialCameraPosition = LatLng(
                                          double.parse(strLatitude),
                                          double.parse(strLongitude));
                                      _createMarker();
                                    });
                                  }
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Icon(Icons.search_rounded,
                                                color: Constants.colorBlack,
                                                size: 18.w),
                                            SizedBox(width: 10.w),
                                            Text(
                                              Languages.of(context)!
                                                  .labelSearchLocation,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Constants.colorBlack,
                                                  fontFamily: Constants.appFont,
                                                  fontSize: 14.sp),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 12.w),
                                    Text(
                                      'OR',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Constants.colorBlack,
                                          fontFamily: Constants.appFont,
                                          fontSize: 14.sp),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 12.w),
                                    InkWell(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isAutoLocateLoading = true;
                                        });
                                        var locations = await Geocoder2
                                            .getAddressFromCoordinates(
                                          latitude: widget.currentLat ?? 0.0,
                                          longitude: widget.currentLong ?? 0.0,
                                          googleMapApiKey: apiKey,
                                        );
                                        setState(() {
                                          strSearchedAddress = locations
                                              .results.first.formattedAddress;
                                          log(locations.results.first.geometry
                                              .location.lat
                                              .toString());
                                          log(locations.results.first.geometry
                                              .location.lng
                                              .toString());
                                          strLongitude = locations.results.first
                                              .geometry.location.lng
                                              .toString();
                                          strLatitude = locations.results.first
                                              .geometry.location.lat
                                              .toString();
                                          _mapsController.animateCamera(
                                            CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                                              CameraPosition(
                                                  target: LatLng(
                                                      double.parse(strLatitude),
                                                      double.parse(
                                                          strLongitude)),
                                                  zoom: 18),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                          _initialCameraPosition = LatLng(
                                              double.parse(strLatitude),
                                              double.parse(strLongitude));
                                          _createMarker();
                                          isAutoLocateLoading = false;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.w),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Constants.colorTheme,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
                                        ),
                                        width: 40.w,
                                        height: 40.w,
                                        child: isAutoLocateLoading
                                            ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                strokeWidth: 2,
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    Constants.colorTheme,
                                                valueColor:
                                                    const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                                                        Colors.white),
                                              )
                                            : Icon(
                                                Icons.near_me_rounded,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                size: 18.w,
                                              ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: strSearchedAddress.isNotEmpty,
                            child: SimpleShadow(
                              opacity: 0.6,
                              color: Colors.black12,
                              offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                              sigma: 5,
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.h),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.w),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Selected Address: $strSearchedAddress',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontFamily: Constants.appFont),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SimpleShadow(
                            opacity: 0.6,
                            color: Colors.black12,
                            offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                            sigma: 5,
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.h),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.w),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text(
                                      Languages.of(context)!.labelHouseNo,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: Constants.appFontBold,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                   
                          SimpleShadow(
                            opacity: 0.6,
                            color: Colors.black12,
                            offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                            sigma: 5,
                            
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text(
                                      Languages.of(context)!.labelLandmark,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18.sp,
                                        fontFamily: Constants.appFontBold,
                                        color: Constants.colorBlack,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 22.h),
                                  TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                      hintText: Languages.of(context)!
                                          .labelAnyLandmarkNearYourLocation,
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                    ),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: Constants.appFont,
                                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                                      color: Constants.colorBlack,
                                 
                          SizedBox(height: 22.h),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: CustomElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (_textFullAddress.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                      dialogShowDialog();
                                    } else {
                                      Constants.toastMessage(
                                          'We are missing your complete address, please add one!');
                                    }
                                  },
                                  buttonLabel: widget.isFromAddAddress
                                      ? Languages.of(context)!.labelAddAddress
                                      : 'Set This & Proceed to Payment',
                               

  dialogShowDialog() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(22.r),
          topRight: Radius.circular(22.r),
        ),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(22.w),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      Languages.of(context)!.labelAttachLabel,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.sp,
                        fontFamily: Constants.appFontBold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: const Icon(Icons.cancel_rounded,
                          color: Colors.redAccent),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.h),
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.w, horizontal: 12.w),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3)),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.new_label_rounded,
                          color: Constants.colorTheme, size: 18.w),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.w),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          controller: _textAddressLabel,
                          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                            hintText: Languages.of(context)!
                                .labelAddLabelForThisLocation,
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: Constants.appFont,
                            fontSize: 14.sp,
                            color: Constants.colorBlack,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 22.h),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.w),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3)),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.public_rounded,
                        color: Constants.colorTheme,
                        size: 20.w,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 12.w),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        strSearchedAddress,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.sp,
                            fontFamily: Constants.appFont,
                            color: Constants.colorBlack),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 22.h),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        Languages.of(context)!.labelCancel,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Constants.colorBlack),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 22.w),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (strSearchedAddress.isEmpty) {
                          Constants.toastMessage(
                              Languages.of(context)!.labelPleaseSearchAddress);
                        } else if (_textAddressLabel.text.isEmpty) {
                          Constants.toastMessage(Languages.of(context)!
                              .labelPleaseAddLabelForAddress);
                        } else {
                          String strAddressLabel = _textAddressLabel.text;
                          if (strAddressLabel.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                            callAddUserAddress(strAddressLabel);
                          } else {
                            Constants.toastMessage(
                                'Please Add Label For Your Location');
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Save',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Constants.colorTheme),
                      ),
               

  Future<BaseModel<CommonResponse>> callAddUserAddress(strAddressLabel) async {
    CommonResponse response;
    try {
      Constants.onLoading(context);
      Map<String, String> body = {
        'address': _textFullAddress.text.toString(),
        'lat': strLatitude,
        'lang': strLongitude,
        'type': strAddressLabel,
      };

      response = await RestClient(RetroApi().dioData()).addAddress(body);
      Constants.hideDialog(context);
      log(response.success.toString());
      if (response.success!) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          Transitions(
            transitionType: TransitionType.slideUp,
            curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
            reverseCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
            widget: const ManageAddressesScreen(),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        Constants.toastMessage(
            Languages.of(context)!.labelErrorWhileAddAddress);
      }
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      Constants.hideDialog(context);
      log("Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      return BaseModel()..setException(ServerError.withError(error: error));
    }
    return BaseModel()..data = response;
  }

  void _updatePosition(CameraPosition _position) {
    Position newMarkerPosition = Position(
        latitude: _position.target.latitude,
        longitude: _position.target.longitude,
        accuracy: 10,
        altitude: 1.0,
        heading: 0.0,
        speed: 10,
        speedAccuracy: 1,
        timestamp: null);

    Marker marker = Marker(markerId: const MarkerId("marker_1"));

    setState(() {
      marker = marker.copyWith(
          positionParam:
              LatLng(newMarkerPosition.latitude, newMarkerPosition.longitude));
    });
  }
}
```

**for a quick view to relevant parts**

**Maker method**

```
Set<Marker> _createMarker() {
    return <Marker>{
      Marker(
        draggable: true,
        markerId: const MarkerId("marker_1"),
        position: _initialCameraPosition,
        icon: _markerIcon,
      ),
    };
  }
```

**Initial value of map**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _markerIcon = widget.marker;
    _initialCameraPosition = LatLng(widget.currentLat!, widget.currentLong!);
  }
```

**GoogleMap**

```
GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: _initialCameraPosition, zoom: 13),
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    markers: _createMarker(),
                    onCameraMove: ((_position) => _updatePosition(_position)),
                  ),
```

**Update Position method**

```
void _updatePosition(CameraPosition _position) {
    Position newMarkerPosition = Position(
        latitude: _position.target.latitude,
        longitude: _position.target.longitude,
        accuracy: 10,
        altitude: 1.0,
        heading: 0.0,
        speed: 10,
        speedAccuracy: 1,
        timestamp: null);

    Marker marker = Marker(markerId: const MarkerId("marker_1"));

    setState(() {
      marker = marker.copyWith(
          positionParam:
              LatLng(newMarkerPosition.latitude, newMarkerPosition.longitude));
    });
  }
```

**On Map created method**

```
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapsController = controller;
  }
```

**Ui view of map**
[image: UI view of map]
What I want(Video descrition)
[enter link description here](https://www.veed.io/view/7c29a1be-3266-4e2f-8dfa-f270013ac45f?sharingWidget=true)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62334555/11445944

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak ok I will try this but with which part of my code I have to replace it, I am working with it first time

Comment: I think you can create `Icon` or `Image` for marker instead of `Marker`. Then put bottom of the marker in the center of the screen. Call `getCenter` on `onCameraMove` and you can get `LatLng` in the center of the screen.

Comment: Add marker `Icon` or `Image` as a child of `Stack` so it will stay in the center of the screen when you move the map.

Comment: Did you found your answer?

Comment: @Vikas nope, can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps

1. create a stack
2. In children of stack place your google maps
3. Second children of the stack should be your marker/icon, positioned at the center, you can use Positioned or Align widget.
4. Use the predefined method of GoogleMaps widget {void Function(CameraPosition) onCameraMove} to get the latitude and longitude of the center of the maps.
   Now you can use the latitude and longitude in any way, maybe store it to firebase, maybe update the map, whatever you want.

Your code will look like this

```
    class MyLocationClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyLocationClassState createState() => _MyLocationClassState();
}

class _MyLocationClassState extends State<MyLocationClass> {
 
  double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(34.0060495, 71.5179581),
              zoom: 14.4746,
            ),
            markers: Set.of([]), //replace this line with your marker/s code.
            onCameraMove: (cameraPosition) {
              currentLongitude = cameraPosition.target.longitude; //gets the center longitude
              currentLatitude = cameraPosition.target.latitude;   //gets the center lattitude
            },

          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: IconButton(
              iconSize: 30,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.place,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
              },
            )
          ),
          //a button if you want to use the saved location
          Positioned(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
              right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: ()
                {
                  //save the currentLongitude, currentLatitude or do something else.
                },
                child: Text('Save'),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: my camera position is using the default map marker and not changing lat long on camera move

Comment: Did you implement the code I shared above or are you still using your code?